# how to apply ternary operator to this code

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

```js
function domainTypees(domains) {
    const domainType = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
        const domain = domains[i].split(".");
        console.log(domain);
        const lastdomain = domain[domain.length - 1];

        //1.5 creta the conditional statements
        /* return lastdomain==="org"?domainType.push("organization")
        :lastdomain==="com"?domainType.push("commercial")
        :lastdomain==="net"?domainType.push("network")
        :lastdomain==="info"?domainType.push("information")
        
        return domainType*/

        if (lastdomain === "org") {
            domainType.push("organization");
        } else if (lastdomain === "com") {
            domainType.push("commercial");
        } else if (lastdomain === "net") {
            domainType.push("network");
        } else if (lastdomain === "info") {
            domainType.push("information");
        }
    }
    return domainType;
}

console.log(domainTypees(["en.wiki.org", "codefights.com", "happy.net", "code.info"]));
```

the problem I have is when I try to apply ternary operator, the if conditions work but I can't apply the ternary operator the right way, can someone please show me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say, don't. A ternary will only make this more confusing.

Comment: Why you want to use ternary operator here? Use switch instead

Comment: Offhand it looks ok. What are you getting when you use the ternary operator compared to the if-else cascade? I agree with evolutionxbox, it will be confusing. I would use a lookup, like `tldWords.get(lastdomain)`

Comment: Hi, please format your code next time. I did it for you this time. You can read about how that works [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to have in the resulting array when you have for example `"somewhere.eu"`?

Comment: I am not trying to compare the if statements with the ternary operator I am just trying to learn how to apply the ternary operator.

Comment: OK then please learn this about the ternary operator: This example is **not** the right place to apply the ternary operator. `a ? b : c ? d : e ? f : g` is unwieldy and frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

Your code would work if you'd remove the `return` in front of the chain of ternaries and added a fallback at the end, like `: 'unknown'` (and also made sure that the `return domainType` stays *outside* of the loop body). But as people in the comments already mentioned, it would make the code much much less readable and maintainable.

Instead, you could either use a switch, like this:

```js
switch (lastdomain) {
  case 'org':
    domainType.push('organization')
    break
  case 'com':
    domainType.push('commercial')
    break
  case 'net':
    domainType.push('network')
    break
  case 'info':
    domainType.push('information')
    break
}
```

...or, for the most concise and least repetitive code, a lookup table:

```js
const typeDescription = {
  org: 'organization',
  com: 'commercial',
  net: 'network',
  info: 'information'
}[lastdomain]

if (typeDescription) domainType.push(typeDescription)
```

This is a literal translation of your code, sort of. But, going one step further, it would seem that you expect an array as output with the same number of elements as the input (otherwise you wouldn't know which is which as soon as you have a TLD that's not in the list, say `.de`). So you would need a default value, for example `unknown`. In this case the `if` would become unnecessary:

```js
domainType.push({
  org: 'organization',
  com: 'commercial',
  net: 'network',
  info: 'information'
}[lastdomain] || 'unknown')
```

However, then we could simplify your whole function as follows:

```js
function domainTypes (domains) {
  return domains.map(domain => ({
    org: 'organization',
    com: 'commercial',
    net: 'network',
    info: 'information'
  }[domain.split('.').pop()] || 'unknown'))
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion by removing the first return but it still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I see now what you mean - specifically for the ternary there was another issue, you were missing the `:` part at the last ternary. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with the sentiment that a ternary statement wouldn't improve readability in this case. Personally, I'd go for the dictionary approach as [suggested in the answer by CherryDT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62975024/1627744) as it's quite simple to add more extensions if there is need.

If you still want to do know how it would be done with the ternary statement, it depends on what you want to have in your result when you receive a domain with an unknown extension. In a ternary statement you always need a final "else" part.

1. Map unknown extensions to `"unknown"`:

```
function domainTypees(domains) {
  return domains.map((domain) => {
    const domainParts = domain.split(".");
    const domainExt = domainParts[domainParts.length - 1];
    return domainExt === "org"
      ? "organization"
      : domainExt === "com"
      ? "commercial"
      : domainExt === "net"
      ? "network"
      : domainExt === "info"
      ? "information"
      : "unknown";
  });
}

domainTypees(["en.wiki.org", "codefights.com", "happy.net", "code.info", "somewhere.eu"])
// results in: ["organization", "commercial", "network", "information", "unknown"]
```

2. Use `flatMap` to filter out the unknown extensions

```
function domainTypees(domains) {
  return domains.flatMap((domain) => {
    const domainParts = domain.split(".");
    const domainExt = domainParts[domainParts.length - 1];
    return domainExt === "org"
      ? ["organization"]
      : domainExt === "com"
      ? ["commercial"]
      : domainExt === "net"
      ? ["network"]
      : domainExt === "info"
      ? ["information"]
      : [];
  }, []);
}

domainTypees(["en.wiki.org", "codefights.com", "happy.net", "code.info", "somewhere.eu"]);
// results in: ["organization", "commercial", "network", "information"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet could help you without changing much of your original code. Have fun conducting experiment

```js
function domainTypes(domains) {
  const domainType = []

  for (let i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
    const domain = domains[i].split(".")
    console.log(domain)
    const lastdomain = domain[domain.length - 1]

    const type =
      lastdomain === "org"
        ? "organization"
        : lastdomain === "com"
        ? "commercial"
        : lastdomain === "net"
        ? "network"
        : lastdomain === "info"
        ? "information"
        : null

    if (type !== null) domainType.push(type)
  }

  return domainType
}

console.log(
  domainTypes([
    "en.wiki.org",
    "codefights.com",
    "happy.net",
    "code.info",
    "other.xyz",
  ])
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function domainType(array){
      let domainType;
      array.forEach(domain => {
             switch(domain.split(".")[1]){
                   case 'org':
                        domainType = 'organization';
                        break;
                   case 'com':
                        domainType = 'comminication';
                        break;
                   case 'net':
                        domainType = 'network';
                        break;
                   case 'info':
                        domainType = 'information';
                        break;
                   default:
                        domainType = 'unknown';
                        break;
              }
              return domainType;
       });
}
```

Instead a doing a for, do a `forEach`, It's cleaner, and instead of using a bunch of `else if` use a `switch` with `case` for each domain (and a `default`. Basically a final `else`) and finally return it.

Comment: That looks a lot cleaner. Thank you very much

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't work though because nothing is returned. (You'd need `map` instead of `forEach` and an outer `return` statement too.) Plus, `domain.split(".")[1]` would fail on subdomains or even things like `somedomain.co.uk`.